# create var's with others

Tags: php

I want to create somthing like 100 var's which their names will be:

```
$numbr_1 = 1;
$numbe_2 = 2;
$number_3 = 3;
...
```

I won't write 100 vars of course, but there is a way to do it with foor loop or somthing? I thought about this:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++)
$number_{$i} = $i;
```

Comment: I'm saying this because I'm a friend, and I don't want you to have to deal with the consequences of what you're attempting: Do NOT create hundreds of ambiguously named variables when you could create a single array with many values.

Comment: it's just an interesting question, i won't use it but I just want how to do it. thank you.

Comment: In that case, follow @Marc B's link below on `variable variables` to get a complete run-down on how they work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're talking about [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), and they are incredibly stupid to use. For one, they make debugging next to impossible.

What you want is an array:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++) {
   $numbers[$i] = $i;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll mark your question in the moment I can.. EDIT: by the way, its just a question i wont use it (variable variable), just know how to do it..

Comment: Variable variables are sometimes needed for cheap reflection, but not in this case I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
for($i = 1 ; $i <= 100 ; $i++){
  $var_name = "number_$i";
  $$var_name = $i;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for($i=1;$i<=100;$i++) {
   $j="number$i";
   $$j = $i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use an array?

```
$number = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++)
{
    $number[] = $i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
       for($i = 1 ; $i <= 100 ; $i++){
            ${'number_'.$i} = $i;
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is usage of array.

```
$number = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++) {
    $number[$i] = $i;
}
```